# How to use fast pitch

Tags: yeast

I am making a recipe of cream ale beer, do I use both the fast pitch and the Wyeast when brewing the beer? Does the fast pitch replace the sugar?

Comment: I believe fast pitch is just canned starter wort. The idea being, you add your fast pitch and yeast in a container, let it ferment, decant off the fermented wort, and pitch that the yeast into your beer.

Answer (score 1):

Fast Pitch is just canned worth with a bit of yeast nutrients. The idea is that you can use this as a pre-sterilised worth to make a starter with your liquid yeast before pitching it into the worth.

It just takes away the trouble of having to use dme and boil it, cool it down, while making a starter.